# angular2+ how to use `${}` syntax interpolation in html

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I know the interpolation usage is like this: `<div>{{user.name}}</div>`, but I found somwhere this syntax was used `<div>${user.name}</div>`.

Does anyone know what's this syntax about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax is apply in **typescript**

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/template-strings.html#string-interpolation

don't forget to enclose with ` and not with ",'

Answer (score 0):

`<div>{{user.name}}</div>`

It's called [interpolation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#interpolation).